# Catch what user tapped (Textview1 or Textview2 or Button1) when keyboardDidShow (via NSNotification)

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard, uiresponder

I would like to intercept what button/textview or #tag the user tapped when I reach the func keyboardDidShow

```
@objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
   
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
               guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {return}
               let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
        
        if isheight == 0.0 { isheight = keyboardFrame.height}
     
               if self.view.bounds.origin.y == 0{
                   
                    self.view.bounds.origin.y += keyboardFrame.height
                  
                   
               }
    }
```

On my VC I have this line to call the func

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow),name:Responder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Is there a possibilty ?

Comment: In case of UITextView, you might check for each textView if they are `firstResponder`. For the button, it's unclear on how the Keyboard would show.

Comment: It's a button that allows to type characters in the screen (after you take a picture). The UITextView is for the title of the picture. I need to know which one is tapped by the user :)